# CSS 100 percent with padding

Tags: css

I am trying to get a overlay div to fit inside its parents borders.
It works for the iframe below it. Not for the blue div on top.

```
#screenoverlay {
    position: absolute;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;       
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;

    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[image: blue overlay]

Comment: Can you please be more precise? I don't really understand your drawing and what you exactly want...

Comment: can you provide JSFiddle for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#screenoverlay {
    position: absolute;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 60px); /* 30px + 30px = 60px negate this from total width, this take care of your div position to be in parent div */
    height: calc(100% - 60px); /* 30px + 30px = 60px negate this from total height, this take care of your div position to be in parent div */
    margin-top: 30px;   
    margin-left: 30px; 
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

    /* margin : 30px; you can club all above in shorthand */

    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

if you have

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

As you have `position: absolute`, you can use `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` instead of using `margin`

```
#screenoverlay {
    position: absolute;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    top: 30px;     
    left: 30px;   
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;


    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 1;
}
```